# How to create a custom jquery carousel?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, carousel, jcarousel

Hi I want to create a simple jquery carousel for my php web application. I am using php5 and mysql.

How can I create that any body can help me?

Comment: Why inventing the wheal? If its for educational purpose go ahead but if its a real time project, its not a good idea. Go to Google and start searching for hundreds of carousels and if you get one for your need use it. If need some changes make changes on that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this tutorial - http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/

Although please note, there are lots of other carousel's out there that you could try/use - e.g. http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/ and http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel/ - so I wouldn't generally recommend starting a new one.

Comment: http://www.jqueryfordesigners.com is a good resource for ui developers. They have very good examples and excellent descriptions.

Comment: @WarFox the site is broken http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://jqueryfordesigners.com

Comment: yup just noticed... M getting 502 bad gateway.. looks like their server is in trouble